# Какой корень у слова "укусил"?

Tags: морфология

Какой корень у слова "укусил"?

Answer (score 1):

Здесь корень "-кус-".

Comment: А НЕ -УКУС?

Answer (score 1):

-кус- корень слова

Answer (score 0):

Не укус: закусить, прикусить, выкусить и т. д.

Answer (score 0):

*кус* я тоже так думаю!

Comment: например, кусачая собака

Answer (score 0):

Приставка -у-,корень-кус-суффикс-ил-